# Displaying special characters on html C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while now and I seem to be getting nowhere.
I've been trying to display special chars on a webpage but I'm having lots of trouble achieving my goal.
I'll use the † symbol as an example to explain my issue.

I'm loading the string from a database so the symbol is stored as \u0086
Let's use the word †est as an example.. When I load the string on CodeBehind I get "\u0086est" and on the webpage I get est instead of the correct symbol.

I've been trying to encode the string in multiple ways but it seems that I'm out of luck as I can't seem to get it to work.
The closest I got was using this:

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(HttpUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes(myString))
```

which returned Â†est ... However I'm not certain if it would be a good idea to specify the codepage like this as I'm loading the strings from a database and other special characters may appear as well.

It would be great if I could get some help.

EDIT:
I'm simply setting a label's text to the string I'm loading from the database.

```
myLabel.InnerText = myString;
```

Comment: How are you trying to display it on the page?  You have shown no example of that

Comment: I'm simply setting a label's text to the string I'm loading from the database. So something like: myLabel.InnerText = myString;

Comment: Include the relevant details in the question, not the comments.  The question itself needs to include a [MCVE]

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: We need a [MCVE], what is `myString`?  Provide a _Complete_ example.

Comment: Have you tried converting to UTF8 string e.g. `byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString); myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);` . Also, set the request and response encodings in page directive `<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>`

Comment: Have you tried html.raw ?